# How do I print multiple variables in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my print statement. I have this snippet of code so far:

```
if ($message =~ /Status changed from (New|In Progress|Feedback) to Completed/) {
    my ($author, $assignee, $target, $issue, $title) = (
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
    );
    if ($message =~ /\* Author: (\b.*)/) {
        $author = $1;
    }

    if ($message =~ /\* Assigned To: (\b.*)/) {
        $assignee = $1;
    }

    if ($message =~ /\* Target version: (\b.*)/) {
        $target = $1;
    }

    if ($message =~ /Issue #(\d+) has been updated by (\b.*)/) {
        $issue = $1;
    }

    if ($message =~ /(Task|Story) #(\d+): (\b.*)/) {
        $title = $3;
    }

    print "Author: $author\n";
    print "Assignee: $assignee\n";
    print "Issue: $issue\n";
    print "Title: $title\n";
    print "Target: $target\n";

    my $result = sprintf("%s completed issue %s %s due on %s\n", $assignee, $issue, $title, $target);
    print "$result\n";

    print "Author: $author\n";
    print "Assignee: $assignee\n";
    print "Issue: $issue\n";
    print "Title: $title\n";
    print "Target: $target\n";
```

And for some weird reason my output is coming out like this:

```
Author: Miguel Morales
Assignee: Miguel Morales
Issue: 1257
Title: Get wireless access to servers
Target: sprint-apr-2
 due on sprint-apr-27 Get wireless access to servers

Author: Miguel Morales
Assignee: Miguel Morales
Issue: 1257
Title: Get wireless access to servers
Target: sprint-apr-2
```

You can see how when I print the variables one at a time, the output gets printed fine, but when I mix the variables up it gets all messed up. Any ideas why? Note I'm new to perl, but I've done some C in the past. I'm not sure if this is related to the $1, $2, $3 variables or the way I'm using sprintf, but I have tried with print, printf and still the same.

Here is a sample `$message`:

```
Issue #1257 has been updated by Miguel Morales.

Status changed from In Progress to Completed
% Done changed from 40 to 90

----------------------------------------
Task #1257: Get wireless access to servers
http://test.sample.com/issues/1257#change-4651

* Author: Miguel Morales
* Status: Completed
* Priority: Normal
* Assigned To: Miguel Morales
* Category: 
* Target version: sprint-apr-2
----------------------------------------




-- 
You have received this notification because you have either subscribed to it, or are involved in it.
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I'll offer that you could probably use a hash here - extract a key-value with `my ( $key, $value ) = split ( ":" ); $results{$key} = $value; ` type logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the `print`, it's that `$message` contains CRLF line endings.  In a regex, `.` matches any character that is not LF (which means it matches CR).  When you print the CR, the cursor goes back to the left margin, causing subsequent text to overwrite what you've already printed.  You don't see this when you print the variables individually, because the next character printed after the CR is `\n` (LF) which moves the cursor to the start of the next line.

Since you don't show us how you acquired `$message`, it's hard to say what the best way to remove the CRs is.  Perhaps you should have opened the file with the `:crlf` layer.

One way to remove the CRs would be

```
$message =~ s/\r//g;
```

before you start extracting the bits you want.  Or, you could replace `(\b.*)` with something that won't extract the CR.  For example, you could use `(.*\S)`, which requires the match to end on a non-whitespace character.

Comment: No idea how you found that out... Nailed it, though.

Comment: @mimoralea, you're not the first person to make that mistake.  I'm sure there's at least a dozen similar questions here.  The result of printing extra CRs is pretty obvious once you've seen it.

Comment: The best way to handle this problem is to `s/\s+\z//` the input string. That will remove any CR, LF, and trailing whitespace all at once